# Add a new section to the wp-admin edit post page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

One of my post types is called Events and on here I have typical things like a post title, body, event date, etc.

In the site's code (on a custom template), I am programmatically adding meta to events when a user signs up (custom array of values).

The problem is that an admin can't see this data.

I wanted to know how I could add a custom section or template so when an admin inside wp-admin goes to any given event, and edits this single post/event, they can see the metadata associated.

I want to just add a new field section somewhere, called "Registrations", and then I'd programmatically access the meta and format it how I want, put some HTML/CSS in there, etc.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Thanks!